# I want the current candle to be lower than the top 3 highest candles

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I want the current candle's high to NOT be among the top 3 highest highs of all bullish candles over a 17-period look-back period. In other words, I want the current candle to be lower than the top 3 highest candles.

Here is what I wrote:

```
BullishCandle = close > open

NotTopThreeHighs = high < ta.highest(high, 17)[3] and BullishCandle
```

I get no error, but the code makes no difference in practice.

Comment: So you are dealing with "four candles" or "fork handles" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and push the `high` when it is a bullish candle.

Then sort this array and check if the current bullish high is less than the third element in the sorted array.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

len = input.int(17, "Length")

var high_arr = array.new_float(len)

is_bullish = close > open

if (is_bullish)
    array.shift(high_arr)
    array.push(high_arr, high)

temp_arr = array.copy(high_arr)
array.sort(temp_arr, order.descending)

high_1 = array.get(temp_arr, 0)
high_2 = array.get(temp_arr, 1)
high_3 = array.get(temp_arr, 2)

plot(high_1, "High 1", color.green)
plot(high_2, "High 2", color.yellow)
plot(high_3, "High 3", color.red)

not_top_three = (high < high_3) and is_bullish
plotshape(not_top_three)
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful. I can't get it to work properly in my strategy, though. For example, the large 4 hour candle on May 25, 2021 still gives a bullish signal, even though it is the number 3 highest bull candle in the previous 17 candles. If it were number 4, it would have been correct.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/OKuRmSbe/

Comment: Which candle are you talking about? What time? I don't think May 25 is visible in the screenshot you shared.

Comment: My mistake -- it should be May 5. I mean the large afternoon candle right between 5 and 6.